# Macbook Air Trackpad click and drag impossible?

Tags: trackpad

I want to do something I think is very simple. Select one or more files, and move those files to a folder. Obviously I can do something like this from the terminal, but sometimes I want to just use finder and a trackpad if I already have the directory open in finder.

So, I select the files I want to move, and then try to click and drag these files as I would with a mouse on any other operating system. However on MacOS, as soon as I try to click to begin the drag motion, the operating system interprets the "click" as a single action, and so a preview window is opened on a single file, and the selection is lost.

How can I do what I think is a pretty basic task? This is honestly very frustrating.

Comment: Have you reviewed Apple’s guides How to use the [Force Touch Trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352) and [Turn on three finger drag on Mac Trackpad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204609)?  This is very good info on all of the features of the Mac Trackpad

Comment: Three-finger drag has worked for me for years, and I use it multiple times a day.

Comment: I'd love to know how to do this on Macs without Force Touch [I'm new to the whole idea of trackpads & so far find them irritatingly intractable ;) - we don't yet know exactly what Mac the OP is on...

Comment: I use the three fingers to swap between workspaces, so I can't use it for drag. Literally every other laptop allows you to click and drag things using the trackpad. And people say apple has a good user experience lmao

Comment: @JLCarveth - it's not wise to antagonise those you're asking help of. Because you have a force-touch trackpad, there's a difference between 3-finger touch & three-finger force touch. "Every other laptop" just doesn't have this degree of control.

Comment: Swap 3 finger workspace swap to 4 finger. Then 3 finger drag can be implemented as detailed above. You'll get used to the change very quickly as you'll drag far more than you will swap workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

You're enacting [Force Touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204352) by pressing through to a second level on the trackpad which in Finder opens Quick Look on the item below the mouse. Either…

- don't press through to that second level, just depress the first level like a normal click, or
- turn off Force Touch in System Settings → Trackpad.

Comment: No idea why this isn't accepted or upvoted more... That's *the* answer.